# AlarmManager won't trigger in specific time

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I've got a problem with the AlarmManager. I'm able to set up the Alarm with this code

```
private void setAlarm(long when) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(NoteActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra("ID", note.getId());
    AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    manager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, when, PendingIntent.getBroadcast(NoteActivity.this, 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Reminder set up", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

This code works well if I set `long when = 5 * 1000; \\For example 5secs later`, but if I use this code

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                    calendar.setTime(date);
                    long selectedDate = date.getTime();
                    long timeSince1970 = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    long timeForAlarm = selectedDate - timeSince1970;

                    Intent intent = new Intent(NoteActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
                    intent.putExtra("ID", note.getId());
                    AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                    manager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, timeForAlarm, PendingIntent.getBroadcast(NoteActivity.this, 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Reminder set for "+calendar.getTime().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

my alarm triggerd  2secs later. What I'm doing wrong? :/ 
I've tried `AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP` and `AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP` but nothing changed.

Please do not check my question as duplicated. I didn't find something to try that solved my problem.

Comment: (Tip: Telling the community not to close something as a duplicate won't change anything if it is truly a duplicate. At the most it will only help it get targeted more for closure.)    :-\

Comment: @JonAdams That's true. haha

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are working in Android Studio (if not - you must switch), click **F1** while your text pointer is on `set` method and read description of [AlarmManager::set](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#set(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)).

> Note: Beginning in API 19, the trigger time passed to this method is
>   treated as inexact: the alarm will not be delivered before this time,
>   but may be deferred and delivered some time later. The OS will use
>   this policy in order to "batch" alarms together across the entire
>   system, minimizing the number of times the device needs to "wake up"
>   and minimizing battery use. In general, alarms scheduled in the near
>   future will not be deferred as long as alarms scheduled far in the
>   future.

Comment: So, is there any way to schedule my alarm? Should I use the permission set_alarm or something like this ?

Comment: Man, I already gave you a link and said how to use docs in AS. Only what you need to do is read. Here copy-past from doc: `If your application has strong ordering requirements there are other APIs that you can use to get the necessary behavior; see setWindow(int, long, long, PendingIntent) and setExact(int, long, PendingIntent).`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of set use setExact

```
 manager.setExact(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, timeForAlarm, PendingIntent.getBroadcast(NoteActivity.this, 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
```

Comment: Didn't work :/ Stil the same problem. Alarm triggered after 2 secs.